# Turn Off 'More Options' In The Azure Media Player

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

How do I turn off or hide the "More Options" item in the Azure Media Player controls menu?

[image: Azure Media Player 'More Options' menu item]

I still need the other controls, so disabling the entire control bar is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Azure Media Player does not have any API to turn off the more options menu as it is used to house the buttons when the control bar is too small to correctly display this.

You can however hide this button with some simple CSS:

```
<style>
    .amp-moreoptions-control{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

You can also add new ideas or requests for Azure Media Player here: 
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/293565-azure-media-player

Comment: Thanks Amit, the css workaround will get the job done :) I noticed that the "more options" button will only be displayed if the player is less than the minWidth property. The minWidth property is set to 600 by default, but I couldn't figure out how to change it. Do you know if it is possible to set a different value for minWidth?

Comment: Great feedback. Currently there isn't way to do so through APIs but this seems like a great suggestion to add to the [UserVoice](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/293565-azure-media-player) page for Azure Media Player.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a custom plugins > controlBarIcons object on the amp consturctor options works well too, like:

```
plugins: {
    controlBarIcons: {
        leftIcons: ["playToggle", "previousTrackButton", "skipBackwardButton", "rewindButton", "fastForwardButton", "skipForwardButton", "nextTrackButton", "playbackSpeedButton", "liveDisplay"],
        middleIcons: ["liveIndicator", "currentTimeDisplay", "timeDivider", "durationDisplay", "volumeMenuButton"],
        rightIcons: ["shareButton", "castToDeviceButton", "audioTracksButton", "subtitlesButton", "captionsButton", /*"qualityButton",*/ /*"moreOptionsButton",*/ "fullscreenToggle"],
        removeOtherIcons: ["qualityButton", "moreOptionsButton"]
    },
}
```

You must put the icons that u don't want to be displayed on the "removeOtherIcons", futhermore this allow you to change the order or or move the icons to other bars.

Comment: I am unable to create plugin in html file. Code : (function () {
    amp.plugin('yourPluginName', function (options) {
    var myPlayer = this;
       myPlayer.addEventListener(amp.eventName.ready, function () {
    console.log("player is ready!");
        });
    });
}).call(this); --------- This code throws an error with no message. I am trying to load in index.html post loading of azure media js.